# Organizing and Calling C# Methods Dynamically

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection

Relatively new to C#, looking for the "best practice" way of doing the following:

I have a class (sensor) with public methods such as "CommunicationStart", "DoThing1", "DoThing2".

Before calling these methods, the class is configured with a sensor "Model"

Based on the model, the public methods should take different code paths.  If I were to do this statically, a switch on model in each public method would do the trick.

I want to do this dynamically to aide long term support.  What is the "proper" approach to wrapping dynamically loaded code in each of the public methods?  Reflection?  Delegates?  Where should the dynamically loaded functions reside?  Should they be in the same class as their public wrappers, or reside in a new class?

I'm looking more for the "correct" approach, and organization, not syntax, as I can sort that out myself.  Thanks much in advance!

Comment: the question is a too abstract to answer. what kind of differences do you expect to have? some cases merit having different classes implementing the same interface with a concrete instance being returned from a factory. some cases you would want to pass in the contractor objects that the class will call, each doing something different but all sharing an interface. and some times a simple switch is best.

Comment: Why can't you just create a new class that inherits this old class?

Comment: I see.  You're recommending that "sensor" become a base class where I define the methods that need to be implemented, then override them in a child class for each "model"?

How would I then avoid code duplication if two "models" have a bunch of methods that have the same implementation?

Comment: So the solution I'm favoring right now is to have a lookup table for each "model" where I define "public method" = "model specific method".  I would then use reflection to wrap the dynamic call to "model specific method" in the public method.  This will allow me to share certain methods between models, while having the flexibility to define new code paths as needed for new models that do things differently.  I'll keep the "model specific" methods in the same class as the sensor fro now.  How does C# community view this?  Acceptable?  Or unusual?

Comment: Looks like a candidate for a [strategy pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/Strategy/c-sharp-dot-net)

Answer (score 1):

I hope I have correctly understood your question.
Here is how I would do to create an extensible system for both common methods and Sensor implementations :

**For handling common code (needed by sensor public methods):**

If your assemblies are loaded dynamically, you could use Reflection to find out all classes that implement a common interface, for example `ISensorMethod` (in a common assembly). All assemblies have to know it.
This interface could have one method, let's say `execute()`, and an identifier to be able to recognize the method, for example `string Key { get; }`.
Each reusable code is by the fact in a separate class (one class per method).

Your master code (the one which loads assemblies) could internally keep a `List<ISensorMethod>` to reference all loaded reusable methods.

**For "sensor" classes:**

You could do the same system: load assemblies dynamically, find out all "`Sensor`" or "`ISensor`" classes.
The public inherited sensor methods could invoke reusable methods by their Key.
For that, you could inject dependency in each `Sensor` class (within constructor or with a property), let's say `IMethodCaller`, to allow them to call methods by their key.

```
public interface IMethodCaller
{
   void CallMethodByKey(string key);
}
```

And then here is a possibility of use:

```
public class ElectricSensor : Sensor
{
   public ElectricSensor(IMethodCaller caller): base(caller)
   {
   }

   public void CommunicationStart()
   {
      base.Caller.CallMethodByKey("START_COMMON");
      base.Caller.CallMethodByKey("INITIALIZE_ELECTRIC");
   }

  // (...) 
}
```

Instanciation of the right Sensor class could be done with a factory design pattern...
There are many possibilities around that, depending on your needs.
I suggest to use Reflection as less as possible, because if an error occurs it is always in a really tricky code, and the source of the problem is often very far... unless all exceptions and errors are handled very carefully with meaningful error messages (clear for developpers to locate the real source of the problem in seconds).

Best regards,